# Error While Deploying Django Application on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, deployment

I have been following a tutorial to deploy my application on Heroku, however, when I try running the application it gives me an error. I was not able to understand the logs properly from Heroku nor find any information over the internet. This is the error that I get when I run the application:

[The error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLnEJ.png)

Hope somebody can answer this or at least let me know where within django project I can find this error. As I need some sort of leads towards this issue. Do let me know if you require further information from me. Thanks

**Editted**

Here is the image of the latest error:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Let us see the **full log**, not as an image but copy and paste the full log, also how do you configure your `.Procfile`?

Comment: I have added the fulll error message from the Heroku log and the .Procfile contains the following line (django_project is the project name): web: gunicorn django_project.wsgi --log-file -

Comment: @MahbubRahman, that file should be called `Procfile`, not `.Procfile`.

Comment: In any case, it looks like you are missing a dependency: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crispy_forms'`. Have you declared that in your `requirements.txt` or `Pipfile`?

Comment: The file is called Procfile not .Procfile and as for requirements.txt, I have imported the crispy_forms and still get other errors except the crispy forms.

Comment: then what is the error?

Comment: "as for requirements.txt, I have imported the crispy_forms"—`import`ing modules and having them declared as dependencies are different things. Please edit your `requirements.txt` file into your question. Do you also have a `Pipfile`?

Comment: I think its something wrong with my gunicorn here is list of requirements.txt: asgiref==3.5.0
backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1
certifi==2021.10.8
charset-normalizer==2.0.12
Django==4.0.3
docopt==0.6.2
idna==3.3
pipreqs==0.4.11
requests==2.27.1
sqlparse==0.4.2
tzdata==2022.1
urllib3==1.26.9
yarg==0.1.9
gunicorn==20.0.4
whitenoise==5.0.1
Pillow==7.0.0
dj-database-url==0.5.0
django-crispy-forms==1.7.2
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-storages==1.7.1

Comment: I dont have a pipfile, is it necessary as most tutorial doesn't really include Pipfile?

Comment: @Chris I have attached image of the latest errors, would mean a lot if you could guide? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to find the issue, where the issue was within the requirements.txt and settings.py. I had inserted some unused packages within Installed_Apps in settings.py, which I removed and produced a new requirements.txt using pip freeze.